# max() arg is an empty sequence in max(listname)

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a program  which accepts a list of numbers and returns the largest number possible by concatenating the list of numbers in Python. But when I execute the code I get following error message `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`. Here is my code:

```
def create_largest_number(number_list):
    l=list()
    m=max(number_list)
    while(number_list!=0):
        m=max(number_list)
        l.append(m)
        number_list.remove(m)
    return l

number_list=[23,45,67]
largest_number=create_largest_number(number_list)
print(largest_number)
```

Sample Input: `23,34,55`
Sample Output: `554323`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`number_list!=0` is always going to be true because `number_list` is a list, not a number, so `while number_list != 0` is an infinite loop, and given that you're removing items from the list on each iteration, the list will eventually become empty. Yet it'll never become *zero*, so on the next iteration your code will attempt to calculate `max(number_list) == max([])`, which is an error.

You can solve it this way:

```
while number_list:  # a.k.a. `while len(number_list) > 0:`
```

Comment: Got it it fixed the infinite loop but i still am getting output as [67,45,23] how can i print the elements of list without square brackets and commas

Comment: @K.Khachne, you can't. As long as you're printing the list itself (`print([67,45,23])`), it'll always be printed with the brackets and commas. You can transform the list a bit though: `print(''.join(map(str, [67,45,23])))`.